# How to keep S3 Region in the Config.properties file

Tags: java

This is my java code.I am retrieving the credentials from `Config.properties` file to my java code. I am getting error while fetching it for Region. Please let me know how to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

```
Confi.properties file
url=
port=
database=
user=
password=
awsid=
awskey=
region=Regions.AP_SOUTH_1
bucket=
s3url=
```

Java file

```
prop.load(inputStream);
String awsid = prop.getProperty("awsid");
String awskey = prop.getProperty("awskey");
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsid, awskey); 
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();
```

Comment: "I am getting error while fetching it for Region" - this code does not fetch the region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the value of `region` in your config file to an enum, problem is - it is read as a string...

Instead, try setting it to:

```
region=ap-south-1
```

`AmazonS3ClientBuilder` has another method `withRegion` which accepts a string as an argument.